# PostgreSQL database migration problem from my Django project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've just finalised my project based on **Django ** and **PostgreSQL ** *locally * on my **Windows 10** machine. When migrating to **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** using **pgAdmin 4**, I'm having problems with the *database*. Despite my efforts to deploy the project with its *data*, the database on AWS does not contain any of the information previously stored locally.

I followed the recommended steps to export my PostgreSQL database with pgAdmin 4 and successfully deployed my Django project on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. However, I can't find the data in the AWS database.

I tried to export my PostgreSQL database from pgAdmin 4 as a backup file. Then I imported this file into my AWS database. I expected all my data, such as tables, records, etc., to be copied from my local database to the database on AWS.

I checked the permissions and configurations to make sure the login details were correct, but the data doesn't seem to have transferred correctly to the database on AWS.

What steps have I missed or what specific configurations are required to ensure the complete transfer of data from my local database to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: "Then I imported this file into my AWS database." Please edit your question to show **exactly** what you did to import the data into the AWS database. How can we point out what steps you missed, when you didn't tell us what steps you took?